# when I tried to logged into my business network as a participant to access that transaction record, I encountered the following error:

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

t: Participant 'org.gowdanar.gfunds.Chit#gfunds-001' does not have 'READ' access to resource 'org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network#empty-business-network@0.0.2-deploy.4'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sounds like you permissions.acl file (ACL rules) do not have the correct permissions.

```
rule AllParticipantsCanAccessTheNetwork {
   description: "Allow all participants to access the network"
   participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
   operation: READ
   resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Network"
   action: ALLOW
}
```

Eg a general set of rules might be per below (rule 2 would supercede the one above FYI):

```
/**
 * Access control rules for mynetwork
 */
rule Default {
    description: "Allow all participants access to all resources"
    participant: "ANY"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.gowdanar.gfunds.*"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule SystemACL {
    description:  "System ACL to permit all access"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.Participant"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminUser {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to user resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "**"
    action: ALLOW
}

rule NetworkAdminSystem {
    description: "Grant business network administrators full access to system resources"
    participant: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.NetworkAdmin"
    operation: ALL
    resource: "org.hyperledger.composer.system.**"
    action: ALLOW
}
```